# I need to get dynamic dependent variable value that increases when the other variable increases in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, dependencies

Like this when x is 1000 and y becomes 0.1 and when x is 2000 and y becomes 0.2 like that in php.
Please help me if you are a good at it.[you can see in here as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeerl.jpg)

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself. 
Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), 
read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There's no way to link variables automatically like that.

Answer (score 0):

if there is a certain ratio between x and y like in your example y=(x/10000). Why you are not just doing simple math in php. `$y = $x/10000` where $x is set by you and $y is set by this formulation. If the `$y` is already set, you can just, re-set it with the same formula which overwrites previous set value. If I understand you properly.

**EDIT UPON COMMENT BELOW:**
Try this simple function below. Check the demo

```
function so_set_y($x){
    return floor($x/1000)/10;
}
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/7DmEY)

Comment: I want to get a fixed value of why when x is 1000 up to 2000 I need to Y to be only 0.1 but if I divide 10k to x then there will be more decimal result like if I divide 1824 to 10k then there will be not 0.1 so ithink you understood.

Answer (score 0):

It seems clear that one variable depends on the other.

Maybe your best course of action would be to encapsulate that logic in a class; something as follows (please keep in mind I did not work on PHP since long time ago so the syntax might be wrong):

```
class MyX() {
  private $value: int = 0;

  public function setValue($value: int) : void {
    $this->value = $value;
  }

  public function getY(): float {
    return round($this->value / 10000, 10);
  }
}


$x = new MyX();
$x->setValue(1000);
print($x->getY());
```

By leveraging magic methods you might get something easier to use. But the main idea is still to keep all logic in a single place.